# Handling a "System.Net.Websocket-Exception : The remote party close the connection without completing the close handshake."?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, websocket, xamarin.android

I can able to chat if I continuously chat. If I leave for a 2-3 mins WebSocket connection close without handshake error message I am getting I don't know how to handle.

Can anyone please help how to handle the exception.i have attached the crash log and here is my code.

[image: Crash Report]

*click thumbnail to see the full error*

```
public async void ConnectToServerAsync()
{
    await client.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://api.testurl.com/ws"), CancellationToken.None);


    UpdateClientState();

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        Refresh();
        while (client.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result;
            var message = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[4096]);
            var allBytes = new List<byte>();
            do
            {
                result = await client.ReceiveAsync(message, CancellationToken.None);   

                for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                {
                    allBytes.Add(message.Array[i]);
                }

            } while (!result.EndOfMessage);
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("End of Message2 :" + result.EndOfMessage);
                Debug.WriteLine("All Bytes :" + allBytes.ToString());
                // Optional step to convert to a string (UTF-8 encoding).
                var serialisedMessae = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(allBytes.ToArray(), 0, allBytes.Count);
                var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChatModel>>(serialisedMessae);
                Debug.WriteLine("Message Count :" + msg.Count);
                if (Chatlist.Count != msg.Count)
                {
                    Chatlist.Clear();
                    foreach (var item in msg)
                    {
                        var details = new ChatModel()
                        {
                            Message = item.Message,
                            MessageFrom = item.MessageFrom,
                            MessageTo = item.MessageTo,
                            RoomId = item.RoomId,
                            _id = item._id,
                            TimeStamp = item.TimeStamp.ToLocalTime()
                        };
                        Chatlist.Insert(0, details);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Invalide message format. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

    void UpdateClientState()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsConnected));
        sendMessageCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
        Console.WriteLine($"Websocket state {client.State}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally when you've completed the work with your WebSocket you need to close it by using something like the following:

```
await client.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "closing websocket", CancellationToken.None);
```

That should solve the problem. Or simply do not re-create the `WebSocket` once it's been opened. I couldn't see the client creation code in your post above, but I'm making a bit of an assumption that for whatever reason it's trying to re-make the `WebSocket`, but it already has an existing connection, and as such throws that error.